# Using Lambda or Linq Get data based on child table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have two tables and there is one to many relationship between them product and price. I want to get first 5 items from product table only if price table has no related record or price update date older than a month.

I have tried this;

```
        DateTime checkdate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);

        var test = (from p in main.product
                    from r in main.price
                    where !p.price.Any() && r.UpdateTime >= checkdate

                    select p.main.productid).Take(5);


                    //webservice will check new prices here
```

So, every single time same records are returning...

Comment: Is this correct for older records? `r.UpdateTime >= checkdate`. I think you need `<=` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your condition contains Or "*only if price table has no related record **or** price update date older than a month.*" you need to change operator AND (`&&`) to OR (`||`) in where condition.

```
var test = (from p in main.product
                    from r in main.price
                    where !p.price.Any() || r.UpdateTime >= checkdate

                    select p.main.productid).Take(5);
```